# @Transient annotation is not working on Elasticsearch document

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

#### After indexing sample tweet entity, *language field* is indexed in elastisearch. What i am doing wrong?

Here is my Tweet class.

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;

@Document(indexName = "test", type = "status")
public class Tweet {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String text;
    @Transient
    private String language;

    public String getId() {
       return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }
    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }
}
```

**Update**

```
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;
import demo.entity.Tweet;

public interface TweetRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Tweet, String>{

}
```

Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner{
    @Autowired
    TweetRepository repo;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        Tweet tweet = new Tweet();
        tweet.setId("1");
        tweet.setLanguage("en");
        tweet.setText("Hello world");
    
        repo.save(tweet);
    }

}
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.test</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- Tried without this -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

application.properties

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name= elasticsearch
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=localhost:9300
```

Result is

```
GET test/status/_search

{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "status",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "id": "1",
               "text": "Hello world",
               "language": "en"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

mm m mm m m m m m m mm n n m n m n m n m n m

Comment: What version of springdata-elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: It's spring boot managed version which is 1.1.3.RELEASE. I also tried 1.2.0.RELEASE

Comment: try adding @JsonIgnore annotation to your attribute

Comment: @JsonIgnore is definitely working but I think it's wrong practice because it'll lose Jackson's serialization on language field.

Comment: I've chequed your example and in my case elasticsearch is not indexing the transient attribute. Can you show us the code where you index the document? Are you using elasticsearchrepository? If no, try to index your document using a repository instead the elasticsearchtemplate

Comment: I have the same problem, already indexing the document with a repository. Any suggestions?

elasticsearch: 1.7.3
spring-data-elasticsearch:1.3.1.RELEASE